# Getting Javascript to work in PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, php, loops, while-loop

I am trying to use Javascript in the following while loop but its only applying to the first iteration. From reading other posts I have a feelings its got something to do with ID's but I didnt really understand.

Heres my code:

```
<html>
<head>


</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
      #wrapper {
      background: #ccc;
      display:none
      }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#wrapper').toggle();
})
});//]]> 
</script>

<?php
$x = 5;
while($x > 0)
{
?>
<button id="button">ExP</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="open" style="display: none;">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php
$x = $x-1;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions very much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: php is server side, javascript is client side - the two can't interact ... however, having looked at your code, there is no javascript inside the php while loop, so the question is misleading!!!... the problem is actually that ID's **must be unique** in an HTML page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead of id.

```
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
      .wrapper {
      background: #ccc;
      display:none
      }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.wrapper').toggle();
})
});//]]> 
</script>

<?php
$x = 5;
while($x > 0)
{
?>
<button class="button">ExP</button>
<div class="wrapper" class="open" style="display: none;">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php
$x = $x-1;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is pretty much the solution, thanks everyone for yer help.

Answer (score 0):

ID's are unique:

- One element can have only one ID
- One page can have only one element with that ID

You can't use `$('#button')` or `$('#wrapper')` since they're not unique.

You can for example use `button0`, `button1`, `button5`, etc. as IDs. For example:

```
<button id="button<?php echo $x; ?>">
```

You could also use classes instead of IDs since they don't need to be unique.

Same goes for `list`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need unique id's.
Alternatively you can use classes to fix this

```js
 $(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next().toggle();
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
 for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
?> 
 <button class="button">ExP</button>
 <div style="display: none;">
  <ul>
   <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<?php
 }
?>
```